# Picture Viewer doen't open any images

Tags: 12.04, eog

Picture Viewer does not seem to open any images. The program starts up, but the screen is blank. I am trying this in a triple monitor set-up in a Hungarian language version of Ubuntu 12.04.2.

I have a video that shows what the problem is on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a51LzTXfZEg)

How do I get Picture Viewer working again?

Comment: OP installed Mint, so this is no-repro

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, in terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall eog
```

enter your password (there's no feedback as you type), press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Hope reinstalling solves it. This is really weird.

---

Let's try to get some helpful error messages.

Please run this in the terminal and post the error messages (if there are any) in your edited question (I think it's less work than making youtube videos :) your choice)

```
eog --gtk-debug=all ~/Desktop/111*.jpg
```

Comment: The problem STill exist !!
The
"sudo apt-get install --reinstall eog"
is not helps !!
www.youtube.com/watch?v=yINkU6PGtw8

 - may i am need a RESTART ?

Comment: Sooo, it is still bad, but sometimes it is work, when i am uses 1 monitor only

Comment: this question is not followed, and NOT relevant anymore to me, 'cuz i am changed a system into a Linux mint 18.
( based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS )